# asp.net routing with web forms--all routs get a 404

Tags: asp.net, routes, http-status-code-404

I have created a web forms app that implements routing.  My applications utilizes Phil Haack's example (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx).  All of my routes receive a 404 error. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IIS are you running?
If you are using IIS6 you have some extra work to do, like enabling wildcards for all extensions.

Also, double check your web.config.  There are a TON of changes that have to be made for that to work.